# Multiple Go routines reading from the same channel

Tags: go, goroutine

Hi I'm having a problem with a control channel (of sorts).

The essence of my program:

- I do not know how many go routines I will be running at runtime
- I will need to restart these go routines at set times, however, they could also potentially error out (and then restarted), so their timing will not be predictable.
- These go routines will be putting messages onto a single channel.

So What I've done is created a simple random message generator to put messages onto a channel.
When the timer is up (random duration for testing) I put a message onto a **control channel** which is a **struct payload**, so I know there was a close signal and which go routine it was; in reality I'd then do some other stuff I'd need to do before starting the go routines again.

My problem is:

- I receive the control message within my reflect.Select loop
- I **do not** (or unable to) receive it in my randmsgs() loop

Therefore I can not stop my randmsgs() go routine.

I believe I'm right in understanding that multiple go routines can read from a single channel, therefore I think I'm misunderstanding how reflect.SelectCases fit into all of this.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type testing struct {
    control bool
    market  string
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    // explicitly define chanids for tests.
    var chanids []string = []string{"GR I", "GR II", "GR III", "GR IV"}
    stream := make(chan string)
    control := make([]chan testing, len(chanids))
    reflectCases := make([]reflect.SelectCase, len(chanids)+1)

    // MAKE REFLECT SELECTS FOR 4 CONTROL CHANS AND 1 DATA CHANNEL
    for i := range chanids {
        control[i] = make(chan testing)
        reflectCases[i] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(control[i])}
    }
    reflectCases[4] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(stream)}
    
    // START GO ROUTINES
    for i, val := range chanids {
        runningFunc(control[i], val, stream, 1+rand.Intn(30-1))
    }

    // READ DATA
    for {
        o, recieved, ok := reflect.Select(reflectCases)
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("You really buggered this one up...")
        }
        ty, err := recieved.Interface().(testing)
        if err == true {
            fmt.Printf("Read from: %v, and recieved close signal from: %s\n", o, ty.market)
            // close control & stream here.
        } else {
            ty := recieved.Interface().(string)
            fmt.Printf("Read from: %v, and recieved value from: %s\n", o, ty)
        }

    }
}
```

```
// THE GO ROUTINES - TIMER AND RANDMSGS
func runningFunc(q chan testing, chanid string, stream chan string, dur int) {
    go timer(q, dur, chanid)
    go randmsgs(q, chanid, stream)
}

func timer(q chan testing, t int, message string) {
    for t > 0 {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        t--
    }
    q <- testing{true, message}
}

func randmsgs(q chan testing, chanid string, stream chan string) {

    for {
        select {
        case <-q:
            fmt.Println("Just sitting by the mailbox. :(")
            return
        default:
            secondsToWait := 1 + rand.Intn(5-1)
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(secondsToWait))
            stream <- fmt.Sprintf("%s: %d", chanid, secondsToWait)
        }
    }
}
```

I apologise for the wall of text, but I'm all out of ideas :(!

K/Regards,
C.

Comment: This code is incredibly more complicated than it could and should be. You'll be able to greatly improve it by going through this: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your channels `q` in the second half are the same as `control[0...3]` in the first.

Your `reflect.Select` that you are running also reads from all of these channels, with no delay.

The problem I think comes down to that your `reflect.Select` is simply running too fast and "stealing" all the channel output right away.  This is why `randmsgs` is never able to read the messages.

You'll notice that if you remove the default case from `randmsgs`, the function is able to (potentially) read some of the messages from `q`.

```golang
        select {
        case <-q:
            fmt.Println("Just sitting by the mailbox. :(")
            return
        }
```

This is because now that it is running without delay, it is always waiting for a message on `q` and thus has the chance to beat the `reflect.Select` in the race.

If you read from the same channel in multiple goroutines, then the data passed will simply go to whatever goroutine reads it first.

---

This program appears to just be an experiment / learning experience, but I'll offer some criticism that may help.

- Again, generally you don't have multiple goroutines reading from the same channel if both goroutines are doing different tasks.  You're creating a mostly non-deterministic race as to which goroutine fetches the data first.
- Second, this is a common beginner's anti-pattern with select that you should avoid:

```golang
for {
    select {
    case v := <-myChan:
        doSomething(v)
    default:
        // Oh no, there wasn't anything! Guess we have to wait and try again.
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

This code is redundant because `select` already behaves in such a way that if no case is initially ready, it will wait until any case is ready and then proceed with that one.  This `default: sleep` is effectively making your select loop slower and yet spending less time actually waiting on the channel (because 99.999...% of the time is spent on `time.Sleep`).

Comment: When I got to bed it occurred to me that I'm treating the (control) channel as a broadcast, which was a big no-no from the start! Thank you for the feedback :-)